# Removing class completely

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I have a class file and I want call it multiple times. It's a class named PopupDialog that extends sprite. After I remove it and add it again, the older one appears as well. I need to delete the older one completely. Here's my code:

```
function onSettings(event:MouseEvent):void {
    addChild(popupDialog);
    popupDialog.init(spWidth, spHeight, dialogSettings);
    popupDialog.addEventListener(CustomEvent.PASS_PARAMS, onProcessedEvent);
    spWidth = spWidth - 50;
    spHeight = spHeight - 50;
}

function onProcessedEvent(e:CustomEvent):void {
    popupDialog.removeEventListener(CustomEvent.PASS_PARAMS, onProcessedEvent);

    if (e.btnName == "close") {
        removeChild(popupDialog);
    }
}
```

This can't actually delete the class. I tried setting it to null however then I started to have some other problems.

Comment: We don't know what happens on popupDialog.init... If you don't create the popupDialog again, then the old reference should be used, so `addChild(popupDialog)` will actually remove it first, and then add it on top. So the problem is that you either create it second time, or you do some magic in `init`..

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't know the init function had something to do with this. here's my class content http://sudrap.org/paste/text/556336/

Comment: Well yeah, if you look at it, you will see it creates new objects and adds them..

Comment: popupDialog is not a class, it's an instance of a class. You need to remove an instance of a class not a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var popupDialog:PopupDialog;

function onSettings(event:MouseEvent):void {
    popupDialog=new PopupDialog();
    addChild(popupDialog);
    popupDialog.init(spWidth, spHeight, dialogSettings);
    popupDialog.addEventListener(CustomEvent.PASS_PARAMS, onProcessedEvent);
    spWidth = spWidth - 50;
    spHeight = spHeight - 50;
}

function onProcessedEvent(e:CustomEvent):void {
    popupDialog.removeEventListener(CustomEvent.PASS_PARAMS, onProcessedEvent);

    if (e.btnName == "close") {
        e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(e.currentTarget);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!